# How to down sample an array in python without a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, downsampling

Is there a *'pythonic'* way to cleanly down-sample without multiple for loops?

This example below is the type of for loop I wish to get rid of.

## Minimum working example:

```
import numpy as np
unsampled_array = [1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19]
number_of_samples = 7
downsampled_array = []
downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(unsampled_array)-1, number_of_samples).round()
for index in downsampling_indices:
    downsampled_array.append(unsampled_array[int(index)])
print(downsampled_array)
```

## Result:

```
>>> [ 1  5  7  9 13 17 19]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need function `np.ix_`, as follows:

```
import numpy as np


unsampled_array = np.array([1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19])
number_of_samples = 5
downsampling_indices = np.linspace(0, len(unsampled_array)-1, number_of_samples).round()
downsampling_indices = np.array(downsampling_indices, dtype=np.int64)

indices = np.ix_(downsampling_indices)
downsampled_array = unsampled_array[indices]

print(downsampled_array)
```

Comment: I don't think the `np.ix_` is necessary at all. You can just go `unsampled_array[ downsampling_indices]`.

Comment: This is great as it also works with non integer down sampling ( ie 10->7 )

Comment: `np.ix_` is very quick. You can compare both approaches.

Comment: Instead of calling np.array with dtype=np.int64, add to the end of the np.linspace command astype(int). Also, instead of using round, I would use np.rint.

Comment: @NoamPeled You are right about `astype(int)` but `np.rint` returns a float for some reason so there is no benefit of `np.rint(x).astype(int)` over `x.round().astype(int)`

Comment: I prefer the "round half to even" approach when rounding floats to integers which are also used as indices.

Comment: Instead of calculating the indices, just use this: unsampled_array.reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0]

Comment: agree with you. i get it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want "real" downsampling, where each value is the mean of k values, you can use

```
unsampled_array.reshape(-1, k).mean(1)
```

Make sure unsampled_array is a np.array. In your case, k=2. That will give you:

> [ 2.  6. 10. 14. 18.]

*** Update**: If you just want to take the first item for each k items, you can use this code:

```
unsampled_array.reshape(-1, 2)[:, 0]
```

Take a look at this plot:

[image]

Comment: You are correct. I didn't mention it in the question but I was initially interested in downsampling objects and downsampling between and to sample sizes. I guess I over simplified the example.